# How to determine data format in QByteArray (ASCII / HEX / Unicode)

Tags: c++, qt, dataformat, qbytearray

I have a software that analyzes the serial communication between a testing machine and their software because I need to grab these values for my software. Most of the components are using ASCII-formats for their communication, but there are some that are using binary data like Modbus, etc. As I use readAll(), I've get the result into a QByteArray and when I print it by qDebug() I can clearly see whether it's ASCII or HEX (HEX-values are printed with \xdf\x01\xff...), but I did not find a way to determine by software what format it is. I think there must be a way to find out this...

Comment: You can only do this by yourself by analyzing the data and see if you find some hints to guess the right protocol.

Comment: As chehrlic said, you would have to analyse it, but you can convert it to hex using the `toHex` command: https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qbytearray.html#:~:text=QByteArray%20QByteArray%3A%3AtoHex%20()%20const

Comment: Perhaps you can get some inspiration based on how the UNIX `file` command works. I understand it does tests on the header to classify a binary file. I would recommend you start by analysing the first, say, 8 bytes. That should help differentiate most common file types. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html

Answer (score 0):

The only 100% proof solution is not guessing at all. You should interpret the data based on the documented format of the source.

Using some heuristics (such as looking at the values of the first n bytes), may work most of the time, but will fail from time to time.